# Updating cache on Apollo Client with writeQuery()

Tags: caching, react-hooks, updates, apollo-client

**not a duplicate** *I have been looking into the [documentations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/), and reading a lot about similar problems, but I haven't found an answer to mine.*

**The problem:** I am NOT getting any response from writeQuery in a console.log(), and the cache is NOT updated after the mutation is completed. I was able to log everything except the results of cache.writeQuery(), however I can't figure it out. Can someone point me out where I am going wrong and how to fix it?

**What I try to do:** remove the (by mutation) removed object from the cache, by replacing the previous data with the new data where the object is removed. And save the updated cache!

**productCategorie Query:**

```
const GET_CATEGORIES_AND_PRODUCTS = gql`
    query GetProductcategories($site_id: ID!, $first: Int!, $page: Int!, $orderBy: [OrderByClause!]){
        productcategories(site_id: $site_id, first: $first, page: $page, orderBy: $orderBy ){
            paginatorInfo{
                count
                total
            }
            data {
            name
            categorie_id
            }
        }
    }
`
```

**CACHE productcategories Query:**

```
$ROOT_QUERY.productcategories({"first":10,"orderBy":[{"field":"categorie_id","order":"DESC"}],"page":1,"site_id":"152"})
paginatorInfo: {} 4 keys
data: { 10 keys
  0: {} 4 keys
     type:"id"
     generated:true
     id:"$ROOT_QUERY.productcategories({"first":10,"orderBy": 
[{"field":"categorie_id","order":"DESC"}],"page":1,"site_id":"152"}).data.0"
     typename:"ProductCategory"
  1: {} 4 keys
  2: {} 4 keys
  3: {} 4 keys
  4: {} 4 keys
  5: {} 4 keys
  6: {} 4 keys
  7: {} 4 keys
  8: {} 4 keys
  9: {} 4 keys
__typename:"ProductCategoryPaginator"
```

**deleteCategorie mutation:**

```
const [deleteCategorie, { loading, error }] = useMutation(DELETE_CATEGORIE, {
            update: (cache, deleteCategorie) => {
                const idToRemove = deleteCategorie.data.deleteCategorie.categorie_id;
                const existingData = cache.readQuery({ 
                    query: GET_CATEGORIES_AND_PRODUCTS, 
                    variables: { 
                        site_id: localStorage.getItem("site_id"),
                        page: (page + 1),
                        first: rowsPerPage,
                        orderBy: [order],
                  }, });
                const deletedObject = existingData.productcategories.data.find((t) => (t.categorie_id === idToRemove));
                const newCats = existingData.productcategories.data.filter((t) => (t.categorie_id !== idToRemove));
                console.log(cache.writeQuery({
                    query: GET_CATEGORIES_AND_PRODUCTS,
                    variables: { 
                        site_id: localStorage.getItem("site_id"),
                        page: (page + 1),
                        first: rowsPerPage,
                        orderBy: [order],
                    },
                    data: {
                        productcategories: {
                            data: [
                                ...newCats
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
```

Any help is welcome, this is the first time I'm trying to update cache!

Comment: Have you tried logging newCats? Is it really removing the deleted category from the list?

Comment: @mfurkangok, thank you for your response. I have logged newCats succesfuly and it has the 9 remaining objects as expected. I was able to log everything except the results of cache.writeQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I had to add a keyField for ProductCategory in typePolicies, because it was looking for 'id' which these objects don't have.

Also I had some old packages like @apollo/react-hooks, that somehow intervene with the caching. For more info look for [updating help](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#updating-imports) in de [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#updating-imports).

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: {
            ProductCategory: {
                keyFields: ['categorie_id']
            },
        },
   })
```

**More information on this and more on caching can be found in one of the apollo blogs:**
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/demystifying-cache-normalization/